# How to read parameter from another servlet sent via HttpClient post?

Tags: java, servlets, httpclient

I have to use HttpClient post from one servlet to another...

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
        "http://localhost:8080/FitsServlets/GisServlet");

post.setHeader("Referer", "http://localhost/something");
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

StringEntity params=new StringEntity("test..");

post.setEntity(params);
HttpResponse responseGis = client.execute(post);
```

I want to read parameter received from another servlet and it doesn't work. This is the code of the servlet that receive the post and need to read params:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    System.out.println("gis..");

    Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();

    while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {

        String paramName = parameterNames.nextElement();
        System.out.println("name:" + paramName);
        String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);

        for (int i = 0; i < paramValues.length; i++) {

            String paramValue = paramValues[i];
            System.out.println("value: " + paramValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean but **does not work**? Can you elaborate in more details please?

Comment: It prints gis..but doesn't read parameters..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think you are trying to read your request payload as a request parameter.

Since you are sending a `String` as an entity to your 2nd `Servlet`, you should open a stream chain to your request underlied `InputStream` and pull out the content:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
  // Do whatever you want here...
  InputStream is = request.getInputStream();      
  if (is != null) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = 
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
  }
  //...
}
```

Comment: I have problems with  String requestBody = IOUtils.toString(input); it gives me an error that I can't use toString()..is not aplicable for arguments InputStream..

Comment: Seems you have refered to the wrong `IOUtils` class.
I will update my answer to use the basic IO stuff with no third party libraries.

Comment: Have you been able to solve your issue? You can accept the answer and upvote it if you are satisfied with it :)